Surface atoms concentration
I have a bulk crystal that contains 4 different elements. I want to cut the crystal in such a way that the atoms at the surface still obey the concentration of each atom in the bulk. At least close. In another way too, I want to keep one element concentration fixed whiles I can vary the others. Any way to do this will be deeply appreciated.
POSCAR                                  
   1.00000000000000     
    -0.0008957508212437    7.0874362554952537   -0.0082024389874065
     0.0173763933325644   -0.0082243265786457    7.0296487758806503
     7.0434138028867981   -0.0008828087401673    0.0173679723506720
   Co   Cr   Fe   Ni
    11    11     5     5
Direct
  0.0001612468302538  0.7546154712506624  0.2498591925067634
  0.0010380197975960  0.2472280232771109  0.2498326121668281
  0.0004549603714126  0.4978868541487965  0.4972150102778051
  0.2479442189414649  0.2526602831859315  0.0044149550323154
  0.2472098645481306  0.7552610435936294  0.5011289898707459
  0.7454175093514233  0.7504938113801161  0.0014602975378250
  0.0010079581925966  0.2518161532997729  0.7501487300692058
  0.2535986889144454  0.2497058716046183  0.4943893192331128
  0.4970913605773886  0.0028767582894593  0.0051028964483790
  0.7481172048431084  0.4980336783640108  0.2505935399421614
  0.7521592485979431  0.2519248747186804  0.4982291969150146
  0.2439805575384965  0.5060134893028423  0.2542355285038699
  0.5013167113831359  0.4888812677902753 -0.0032190099260401
  0.4991063733697291  0.7481225697246102  0.2469864236986472
 -0.0014760126470341  0.0078175206162797  0.5037519164117907
  0.2415546338338005  0.0000398861102287  0.2447364379272418
  0.5051858330589953  0.2586196133551067  0.2520933206442162
  0.5009758831141976  0.7470936128925943  0.7562799975713898
  0.7606942477282315  0.2414441616646502 -0.0042711711732083
  0.7607436572082868  0.7449355430021023  0.4957202617599541
  0.2441305928314536  0.0075766795692013  0.7541900463789802
  0.7519399999774666  0.0009622060714492  0.2482908053168321
  0.2508473085151024  0.7492174509483486 -0.0010124871360529
  0.0016960392134960 -0.0031106524186362 -0.0008660179219600
  0.0003313725676426  0.7431152662441280  0.7513848746085743
  0.5026076552714317  0.5044916815548642  0.5056554180845084
  0.7470197667447199 -0.0014936771171350  0.7460916151910306
 -0.0017836048525249  0.5030502035240833  0.0031608462208329
  0.2487421310215092  0.4972123611274926  0.7474664645076691
  0.4970162877144480 -0.0021826292533111  0.4969221616950880
  0.4989634101979317  0.2480020867448189  0.7490729574345159
  0.7522068752437205  0.4976885354332179  0.7509548702019637

